# Competition of Gamma Distributions

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

Consider two random variables $X$ and $Y$ with the same distribution.
I use the phrase *competition of [distribution]* to characterise $\Pr(X > Y)$.

- Competition of Exponentials:
  $$ \Pr( \text{Exp}(\lambda) > \text{Exp}(\mu) ) = \frac{\mu}{\lambda + \mu}. $$
  Here $\text{Exp}(\lambda)$ has *rate* $\lambda$ and *mean* $1/\lambda$.
- Competition of Gaussians:
  $$ \Pr( N(\mu, \sigma^2) > N(\lambda, \nu^2) ) = ... \text{(I forget the formula)}. $$
  One could also impose $\sigma = \nu = 1$ to get a $1$-parameter family

It's a long shot, but is anything known for *Competiton of Gammas*, in the sense of a $1$-parameter family $\Gamma(k, \lambda)$ with $k \in \mathbb N$ fixed. Eg,
$$ \Pr( \Gamma(2, \lambda) > \Gamma'(2, \mu) ) = \Pr( \Gamma(2, 1) > (\lambda/\mu) \Gamma'(2, 1) ) = ... $$
where the random variables are independent (I used a $\prime$ to indicate this).

This is some sort of interpolation between exponentials and Gaussians: $\Gamma(k, \lambda)$ converges (in some sense) to a normal distribution as $k$ grows and is just $\text{Exp}(\lambda)$ when $k = 1$.
What about $k \in \{2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$?

Comment: The same distribution or the the same family of distributions?  For independent (or exchangeable) identically distributed random variables where the probability of equality is $0$, the answer would be $\frac12$

Comment: Different parameter $\lambda$, as in the exponentials and normals :) -- I'll add this clarification :)